# jQuery Mobile Button Formatting

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I posted a general question late last week and it got shut down, so I'll do my best to ask a more specific one.

I'm working on a project with jQuery Mobile and I find that customizing has been extremely difficult. What advantage do the data-* attributes serve? I suppose if you really want to use jQuery Mobile predefined styles for objects it's a good thing, but I find overriding some of the styles to be quite annoying.

I'm just wondering if they're there for anything other than styling. Can I still fire off events and what-not within jQuery mobile without using them? A n00b question I know, I just don't want to step on any landmines later in development because of a poor assumption I've made early on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that explains how to do advanced customization of the jQuery Mobile buttons. The articles show how to do some basic customization, how to reset the jQuery Mobile theme, and how to turn the default button into anything you want:

http://appcropolis.com/blog/advanced-customization-jquery-mobile-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

`data-*` attributes are really important: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html

They are an easy way to define/change content without using raw javascript.

Comment: Based on this it does seem like they are used mostly as a convenience to the framework, but it's still possible to get into the nitty gritty without them. That's exactly what I needed to hear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`data-*` attribute are HTML5 related not jQM:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

How to customize the look and feel:

- http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

It has yet to be seen but a jQM download builder is in the works so you can pick and choose what functionality you need and forget the rest.

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/29/jquery-mobile-1-0rc1-released/

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 10k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool launch as part of 1.0 final in some form. We’re working on a
>   dependency map now for all the plugins to support this tool.

If you are inclined to you can head over to the repo and download what you need:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/js

I think jQM core is still required but I'm not positive on that

Also in your question title you have button formatting

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html